# Is it better practice to use static factory methods over an interface implemented by many different objects?

Tags: java, oop, interface, instantiation, static-constructor

It seems as though you could either use static factory methods or you can use an interface that many objects implement to make it easier for users (or yourself) to instantiate the correct object.

Therefore, it seems to be a decision between, on the one hand, having giant objects with many static factory methods or on the other hand, having an interface that many different objects implement, so many so it would becomes hard for the user to know where to even start.

Example 2: A class with many static factory methods:

```
FooObj foo01 = FooObj.bigFoo();
FooObj foo02 = FooObj.smallFoo();
```

Example 1: An interface with many classes that implement the interface.

```
Foo foo1 = new BigFoo();
Foo foo2 = new SmallFoo();
```

Comment: please create a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example
(more specific, write some code examples)

Comment: Why? It's completely clear what I'm talking about. Interfaces are instantiated through objects and those objects have constructors that dictate how the interface is instantiated. Static constructors do the same thing except without the need for more than one object and without an interface.

Comment: There are no "static constructors" in Java. You must be referring to the factory method pattern, which has a slightly different use case from a Constructor. It is used when the caller does not know what actual instance is being chosen, and depending on some other contextual information the factory method choses the right class and calls its constructor internally.

Comment: Your question is completely clear to _you_ since you're the one who has thought and reasoned about the question, presumably for some decent amount of time. That's not to say your question is gibberish to other people—some or even most may understand it, or at least the gist of it—but it's not necessarily _completely_ clear to everyone. One language that we all (hopefully) speak, however, is code and giving examples in code can make your intentions that much clearer.

Comment: @Slaw Fair point.

Comment: @jbx Static methods that use private constructors.

Comment: @KeepAtIt yeah I explained why they are slightly different than public constructors. Static methods that call private constructors are following the _factory method_ pattern. It is usually when you want to do some logic _before_ allowing your class to be instantiated and possibly choose between different sub-types of the same interface/abstract class.

Comment: @jbx Factory method then, it's still a static constructor. Wouldn't you agree, it's an overcomplication and redundancy to use it with different subtypes of the same interface/abstract class?

Comment: No it is not an overcomplication at all. There are circumstances where the caller cannot know which subtype to instantiate. Maybe it depends on context, or some other business logic. There may also be certain logic you want to do _before_ calling the constructor, which the caller is not aware of.

Comment: @jbx They are doing the same thing except we're acting like they are not. You can do that with an entirely different class that implements the interface.

Comment: @KeepAtIt No they are not doing the same thing. You are just not experienced enough to have encountered situations where it was evident that with just a constructor it would be messy to achieve the same things that you achieve with a factory method. A simple example is Java's old Calendar. It doesn't offer you a constructor, it offers you a factory method `getInstance()`. This internally decides what to give you, and if you are using it on a westernised computer it will give you a `GregorianCalendar`, while on other locales it might give you another Calendar implementation.

Comment: @jbx I don't see how that example proves the point. Not that I'm saying it doesn't, but I don't see how it does.

Comment: @KeepAtIt maybe you should just clarify what you are asking then. I gave you a clear example where using a public constructor does not fit the design required.

Comment: @jbx All this is said respectfully. Could you not just use a class that does the same thing, calling it "new LocalizedCalandar()" and isn't getInstance() just a style choice because of the redundancy.

Comment: @KeepAtIt No it is not style choice. Why should the caller do the logic to choose the localised calendar? This is evidently calendar related logic that should reside in the calendar class. But it needs to happen _before_ the calendar instance is constructed and determines which concrete class is actually chosen.

Comment: As it is your example doesn't make much difference. There is a subtle difference that if you do a static import of `FooObj` its static methods will be accessible without prefixing them with `FooObj`, which might be easier to use in longer expressions. The question still is, is `FooObj.bigFoo()` doing exactly the same as `new BigFoo()` or is it doing other logic? Could it in the future decide to instantiate a `SpecialBigFoo` or `EvenMoreSpecialBigFoo` under certain circumstances?

Comment: @KeepAtIt that is just the simplest example I could think of. There are plenty of other examples around, and with experience you will start facing the decision too. There are other advantages another answer below has listed, like object caching for example, or giving a more descriptive name to the flavour of object you are returning like for example `Collections.emptyList()` is clearly saying it is an empty list (irrespective of what the implementation actually is).

Comment: @jbx Good answer. Yes, the names will start getting quite verbose. Thank you for taking the time to do this back and forth with me. It has helped me greatly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question which you are thinking is answered in the famous book. Effective Java, 3rd Edition by Joshua Bloch. Note that Joshua Bloch is also developer of multiple Java SE classes as well.

Quoting from the book:

> ITEM 1: CONSIDER STATIC FACTORY METHODS INSTEAD OF CONSTRUCTORS

Joshua gives following reasons for using static factory method in place of the constructors

> - One advantage of static factory methods is that, unlike constructors, they have names
> - A second advantage of static factory methods is that, unlike constructors, they are not required to create a new object each time
>     they’re invoked.
> - A third advantage of static factory methods is that, unlike constructors, they can return an object of any subtype of their return
>     type.
> - A fourth advantage of static factories is that the class of the returned object can vary from call to call as a function of the input
>     parameters.
> - A fifth advantage of static factories is that the class of the returned object need not exist when the class containing the method is
>     written.

Joshua also tells problems with the static factory methods

> - The main limitation of providing only static factory methods is that classes without public or protected constructors cannot be subclassed.
> - A second shortcoming of static factory methods is that they are hard for programmers to find.

Java.util.Collections can be seen as an example for static factory method. Quoting from the book

> For example, the Java Collections Framework has forty-five utility
>   implementations of its interfaces, providing unmodifiable collections,
>   synchronized collections, and the like. Nearly all of these
>   implementations are exported via static factory methods in one
>   noninstantiable class (java.util.Collections). The classes of the
>   returned objects are all nonpublic.

Further the author echoes your thoughts

> The Collections Framework API is much smaller than it would have been
>   had it exported forty-five separate public classes, one for each
>   convenience implementation. It is not just the bulk of the API that is
>   reduced but the conceptual weight: the number and difficulty of the
>   concepts that programmers must master in order to use the API. The
>   programmer knows that the returned object has precisely the API
>   specified by its interface, so there is no need to read additional
>   class documentation for the implementation class. Furthermore, using
>   such a static factory method requires the client to refer to the
>   returned object by interface rather than implementation class, which
>   is generally good practice (Item 64).

Java Standard Library makes extensive use of the static factory method because of the advantages suggested by Joshua Bloch. Another example is the valueOf function in the java.lang.Boolean class. The valueOf static factory method beautifully provide you the same object again and again (basically caching)

```
public static final Boolean TRUE = new Boolean(true);
public static final Boolean FALSE = new Boolean(false);
public static Boolean valueOf(boolean b) {
    return (b ? TRUE : FALSE);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Whether you expose Constructors publicly or whether you hide them and only expose a *factory method* that then decides how and when to instantiate a class is a design decision that depends on whether you want to do logic before instantiation, or whether the decision of which concrete class to be instantiated is not up to the caller.

Quoting wikipedia:

> the factory method pattern is a creational pattern that uses factory methods to deal with the problem of creating objects without having to specify the exact class of the object that will be created. This is done by creating objects by calling a factory method—either specified in an interface and implemented by child classes, or implemented in a base class and optionally overridden by derived classes—rather than by calling a constructor.

One example where this takes place in Java is the `Calendar` class, which is `abstract` and does not provide a public constructor. Instead it provides a `getInstance()` method which does some logic to determine which is the right concrete instance to instantiate for the caller.

Comment: Yes, you've correctly pointed out that I was referring to the factory pattern above as static constructors. However, the whole point of having many classes that use an interface is to separate how you want that interface instantiated.

Comment: Yes, but the decision of which class to use is not always that of the caller. When it is not, or when there is logic that the caller cannot or should not do around the instantiation of the object, that is where a factory method comes in. You have not provided any examples so I fail to see how you are expecting more explanations.

Comment: Fair point, I added some code on top.

Comment: Again, thank you for the back and forth, here and above. Talking about it cleared up some issues.